# SO Japanese doesn't show up very well in the SE list of all sites

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com

I was just looking through the list of Stack Exchange sites, and the row for [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/) looks a little messed up.

[image]

It's pretty impressive to get 14 questions per day from zero visitors, although it's a fair bit less impressive to still have zero visitors per day after being active for 2013 years and eleven months.

I'm assuming that these are the same problem, and the property for the site starting date is still set to the default value of `DateTime`, which is[`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), or January 1, 0001 at 00:00.

Comment: wow, 2013 years?!?!? maybe a Shogun or two had posted...lol